# Is there any api that can be used to find a company's NACE code (industry code)?

Tags: data-request, api, companies

I have ca. 30k European company names mainly from Germany, Iberia, France, Benelux and Austria  (SMEs<sup>*</sup>) and their addresses.  In 2/3 of cases I also have a national ID ([SIREN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIREN_code) for French companies, [CIF](http://www.spaincorp.com/vat-number.php) for Spanish companies...)
Is there a way to get the respective [NACE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_Classification_of_Economic_Activities_in_the_European_Community) (2008 version) codes of those companies? There are commercial outlets who do this for around 30 cents a pop but something cheaper would be appreciated.

<sup>* [Small and medium sized enterprises](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_and_medium-sized_enterprises)</sup>

Comment: Apart from the mentioned France and Spain, what are the jurisdictions you are looking at?

I am working on adding the French companies data to [Unigraph](http://unigraph.io), you will then be able to query it and extract it.

Are you sure that the Siren APE Code "Activité Principale Exercée" equals NACE? I am also preparing the Belgium companies, which thankfully are reported with NACE (2003 and 2008) so version should also be probably considered...

Comment: Update: I've added the data on the Belgian and French companies and their NACE, INSEE APE codes into Unigraph. [This example](http://bit.ly/2kNpF1b) shows you how to query it by company name or id and get the NACE 2003/8 or APE

Answer (score 1):

I think the cheapest API for this job is the [OpenCorporates](https://api.opencorporates.com/documentation/API-Reference#industry_codes) one.

With the [Basic subscription](https://opencorporates.com/api_accounts/new) (99 £ and 20 000 api calls a month, or even free if your project is for public benefice), you could match your companies in two months. Or maybe less if you have a lot of Belgian enterprises : i don't know for other countries, but the Belgian Companies database is freely available and it mentions the Nace codes.

Notice that OpenCorporates has also a free Open Refine API that would allow you to reconcile your 1/3 companies without official ID.

Comment: Here is a sqlite version of the Belgian companies database if you want it : [Dropbox link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n3kq4p0vdguae7z/bce.db?dl=0). It is based on CSV downloaded from [here](https://kbopub.economie.fgov.be/kbo-open-data/login?lang=fr) in February.